# Can I stream 1080p video from the Pi?

Tags: video, media, media-server, performance

We all know the Pi can play 1080p video no problem, but is it fast enough to act as the basis for a file server that can stream 1080p video over its wired network connection?

I'm thinking of using mine as a media server of sorts to stream 1080p HD video, (with DTS-HD audio), and I am interested to know if anyone else has tried it or if the Pi is up to the task.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I tested network throughput with `iperf` and it can push around 90 Mbps of TCP through happily. If I recall corectly, Full HD video requires around 25-35 Mbps, so my guess would be that yes.

You may want to consider something faster than a SD card to store media files on. While a Class 6 is probably enough, Class 4 probably isn't.

**UPDATE:**
I did a more realistic test of I/O - reading from SD card and pushing the data over the network.

On Raspberry Pi (Raspbian):

```
nc 192.168.105.225 337 < /dev/mmcblk0
```

On another machine on the same LAN (bridged):

```
nc -l 337 > /dev/null
```

The router (bridge) showed 44 Mbps of traffic being pushed by Pi. Considering that I have a Class 4 SD card this implies that I/O on Pi is not a bottleneck at these speeds.

Resource consumption during a test (it's quite high):
[image: top]

I will try with an attached USB hard drive soon to see if it can push a full 100 Mbps.

Comment: Thanks for that. Sure, a USB hard drive (externally powered) seems like what I'm going for in terms of storage at present.

Comment: I retested just to be on the safe side and it is actually slightly less - around 90 Mbps, but still well enough for streaming.

Comment: A Class 6 SD card should be capable of 6**MB**ps read speeds (6 Mega*bytes* per second), so unless there is some limitation in the Raspberry Pi SD interface, a class 10 card should be more than capable of saturating a 100mbps (100 mega*bit*s per second) once protocol overheads are taken into account.

Comment: Cool- I will have to give that go. How did you get 90mbs? reading your flash or usb stick? writting?

Comment: @ppumkin `iperf` tests only network performance. If I recall correctly, it sends `0123456789` repeatedly. Will do a test  with SD card I/O soon and let you know.

Comment: @ppumkin See my edit.

Comment: Yea- By definition if the USB Hub runs at High Speed then you have 480mbs bandwidth almost 5 times that LAN needs.. so there should not be any problems. But if it does not run at full sped for whatever reason.. This is really providing some good feedback. PS - Can you monitor the CPU load while doing this?

Comment: @ppumkin Yes, see my edit.

Comment: Wow. So are you happy to say that using LAN direcly influences the CPU? Do you think that if something was already running an intense arithmetic procedure (eg video encoding) it would impair reading the SD card.. and cut the throughput to LAN?

Comment: I am not happy, of course not :) But it is understandable. Even TCP itself is quite a resource-intensive protocol. It has to calculate checksums all the time, fragment data, take care of retransmittions, ..

Comment: That is a very good point. Thinkning that the chip is LAN chip you would have expected the LAN module to do this independent of the BCM CPU core? I think something else is causing the CPU to spike.. data shifting from SD to the LAN bus(USB) not sure what it is.